# Script/Bash: How to add if-statement and check fatal error?

Tags: git, bash

I just wrote a small script that pulls from a GIT repository and then runs two commands.

I like to add a if statement when the password is entered wrongly not to run the two other commands  so far I have

```
  #!/bin/sh
echo Pulling GIT repository and do command1 and command2. Press Enter to start...
read
cd /myProjects
git pull 
printf  "\n \n command1 will start now  \n \n"
command1
printf  "\n \n command2 will start now \n\n"
command2
echo Finished. Press Enter to exit ...
read
```

I guess something of the following would be good. I just can not find out what to put into the if condition.

```
 #!/bin/sh
    echo Pulling GIT repository and do command1 and command2. Press Enter to start...
    read
    cd /myProjects
    git pull 
if [ the Password was wrong ] ; then
   printf  "\n \n command1 will start now  \n \n"
    command1
    printf  "\n \n command2 will start now \n\n"
    command2
    echo Finished. Press Enter to exit ...
    read
else
  echo Your password was wrong
fi
```

Note the output for a wrong password is:

```
fatal: remote error: Invalid username or password.
```

Comment: Does git return a status code you can check?

Comment: @AlG: Not sensible ones. It returns 1 for almost every error.

Comment: @AIG Of course it does. `git whatever || exit` should be all it takes. As long as you don't care exactly why it failed, this is good enough.

Comment: @tripleee It was too simple! thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tripleee had the right answer. Another way to write that is:

```
if git pull; then
    command1
    command2
fi
```

Presumably, git pull's error output will be sufficiently clear that you don't need to add your error message.

Answer (score 0):

An even better way to write this in bash is the following.

```
git pull && command1 && command2
```

This will result in following behavior. If git pull secceeds it executes command1, if command1 succeeds it will execute command2.

In case you want command2 to also be executed no matter if command1 fails you write it as following.

```
git pull && command1 || command2
```

This will result in command1 and 2 to be executed only if git pull succeeds.

Other options for more advanced things are using the `$?` variable which gives you the numeric exit code of the last command executed. In bash usually `0` if the command succeed or any number from `1` or higher to indicate the specific failure case.

This allows you to do more advanced stuff like

```
if [ $? -gt 0 && $? -lt 5 ] ; then
    command1
elif [ $? -eq 6 ] ; then
    stuff
else
    things
fi
```